# How to update all columns in dataset except one column(CustName)

Tags: vb.net

Im working on account rights management but i need to update all columns in a table in sql database from datagridview inputs except for one specific column. Thankyou!

```
ID | custName | Active | Group

1  | Wanglu Lu|   1    |   1
2  | Levis Bel|   0    |   2
```

```
Dim comm As New SqlCommand
Dim dbread As SqlDataReader
Dim adptr As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim myBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder

Private Sub lbldgvUserID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbldgvUserID.TextChanged
    Try
        conn.Open()
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandText = "SELECT ID,custName,Active,Group FROM tbl_customer WHERE ID= '" + lblUserID.Text + "'"
        End With
        adptr.SelectCommand = comm
        'dt.Clear()
        ds.Clear()
        adptr.Fill(ds, "tbl_customer")
        dgvPermissions.DataSource = ds.Tables("tbl_custorer").Rows(0)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        conn.Close()
        End With
    End Try


    Dim builder As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adptr)

    adptr.Update(ds, "tbl_customer")
    MsgBox("Customer info successfuly updated!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
```

Comment: If you don't want to accept the default behaviour then don't use a command builder.  Create your own commands for the data adapter and then they'll do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do update column name after getting the result in a dataset. Here is a snippet.

```
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin");
        table.Columns["Dosage"].ColumnName = "Dosage1";
```